# Python: How best to parse csv and count values for only a subset

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with the following contents in 3 columns and 11 rows, the first row being a header. I created this myself to have a simple file to learn from. Each line item is a single order of fruit.

```
OrderNo      Fruit     Origin
1           Apple        NY
2           Orange       FL      
3           Banana       CA
4           Pear         NJ
5           Grapes       VA
6           Grapes       VA
7           Grapes       MD
8           Grapes       MA
9           Pineapple    HI
10          Grapes       GA
```

I am trying to parse this data in Python, to do the following:

(1) determine the states that generate the most orders for each type of fruit and (2) determine the highest number of orders from any single state per each fruit, (3) output this result in alphabetical order like so:

```
Apple NY 1
Banana CA 1
Grapes VA 2
Orange FL 1
Pear NJ 1
Pineapple HI 1
```

After reading the csv file with csv.reader, I was trying to accomplish the counting with Counter and for loops:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter 

cnt = Counter()
f = open("/test.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
header = next(f) 

for row in reader:   
    cnt[row[2]] += 1
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: what do you want to output if 2 states have the same number of orders for a particular fruit? and if there are no orders for some fruit are you happy to not include that fruit in the output at all?

Comment: just caught a typo, output should show 2 after VA since there are 2 orders there, which is the max for that fruit. if there are 0 orders for any fruit then there is no output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd actually use pandas which is a combination of list/dictionary/spreadsheet/database.  It is specifically designed for manipulating data in this way.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

path_to_file = "/test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)

groups = df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Origin'])
max_for_fruit = defaultdict(int) #first pass through the groups, store the maximum for each fruit to handle ties

for g in groups:
    fruit, count = g[0][0], len(g[1])
    max_for_fruit[ fruit ] = max( max_for_fruit[fruit], count )

for g in groups:
    fruit, state, count = g[0][0], g[0][1], len(g[1])
    if count == max_for_fruit[ fruit ]:
        print( "{} {} {}".format(fruit, state, count ) )
```

And here is the output.

```
Apple NY 1
Banana CA 1
Grapes VA 2
Orange FL 1
Pear NJ 1
Pineapple HI 1
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: A couple questions: (1) what code or property is sorting the list alphabetically? (2) anyway to do this with a regular dict instead of a defaultdict(int)? I am trying with a regular dict but am having trouble with the max and count.

Comment: The sorting is automatic, you can pass 'sort=False' to groupby if you don't want them sorted and kept in the original order.  I used defaultdict because I wanted the first comparison to be with zero (since you can't have negative fruit it is safe).  You can use a regular dict, but then you would have to add extra logic to handle the first case where you have no previous value for the fruit.

     if fruit in fruit_dict: do comparison from above code
     else: fruit_dict[fruit] = len(g[1]) #initialize it with the first value)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine and will work great, but you will need two levels of nesting (by fruit and counts by state.  One other little improvement is to used named tuples for clarity:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, namedtuple, defaultdict
from itertools import imap

reader = csv.reader(data)
Order = namedtuple('Order', next(reader))

state_orders = defaultdict(Counter)
for order in imap(Order._make, reader):
    state_orders[order.fruit][order.origin] += 1

for fruit, counts_by_state in sorted(state_orders.items()):
    state, cnt = counts_by_state.most_common(1)[0]
    print '%s is ordered most by %s with %s orders' % (fruit, state, cnt)
```

While dicts and counters handle this kind of problem easily, you're probably better-off using the *sqlite3* module.  SQL was born to solve these kinds of problems:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

reader = csv.reader(data)
header = next(reader)

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE Orders (order_no integer, fruit text, origin text)')
c.executemany('INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (?,?,?)', reader)
c.execute('''CREATE VIEW StateOrders AS
             SELECT fruit, origin, COUNT(*) as cnt
             FROM Orders GROUP BY fruit, origin ''')

for fruit, state, cnt in c.execute('''
    SELECT fruit, origin, cnt
    FROM StateOrders AS Outer
    WHERE cnt = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM StateOrders WHERE Outer.fruit = fruit)
    ORDER BY FRUIT '''):
        print '%s is ordered most by %s with %s orders' % (fruit, state, cnt)
```

Comment: I'd suggest that pandas is a lot cleaner for this sort of thing... See my solution.

Comment: Pandas is great if you've got it.  That said, a person should know how to use straight Python right out of the box.

Comment: How acceptable is it to access protected members like `Order._make` ?

Comment: In a namedtuple, all of the methods are prefixed with an underscore to prevent a namespace conflict with the user defined field names.   So, these methods aren't private.