# How to count items and frequence in csv file python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So. Based on [THIS ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837877/python-how-best-to-parse-csv-and-count-values-for-only-a-subset) and [THIS ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343769/how-to-check-frequency-in-csv-file-on-python) I want to check simple information.

I want to check frequency type of product, status, and cash:

Structure of csv:

```
  ID    Produkt Date1   Date2   Date3   Cash    Status
2383    AAAB    05.02.2020          0.00    Click
3271    AAAB    06.02.2020          0.00    Send
7139    AAD 07.02.2020          0.00    Send
6627    DSV 08.02.2020          0.00    Send
3184    ZXS 09.02.2020          0.00    Raport
4683    ZXS 10.02.2020          0.00    Raport
9982    RESAL   11.02.2020          100.00  Other
```

So I want print:

```
AAAB - CLICK - 1 - CASH 0
AAAB - SEND - 1  - CASH 100
```

I learn python and wrote someting like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

path_to_file = "file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)

groups = df.groupby(["Produkt", "Status"])
max_for_produkt = defaultdict(int)

for g in groups:
    produkt, count = g[0][0], len(g[1])
    max_for_produkt[produkt] = max(max_for_produkt[produkt], count)

for g in groups:
    produkt, status, count = g[0][0], g[0][1], len(g[1])
    if count == max_for_produkt[produkt]:
        print("{} {} {}".format(produkt, status, count))
```

BUT - its give me info only about 1 status and I don't know how to print info about cash :)

Answer (score 0):

`format` function needs to know which argument is mapped with which value.

Change your print statement to following:

```py
   print("{0} {1} {2}".format(produkt, status, count))
```

That way produkt, status, count are mapped properly.